# How to make stored procedure dynamic search with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How to make stored procedure dynamic search with `SQL Server` with name table and name filed and value filed

```
select * from @nametable where @filedname = @valuename
```

Comment: A table name cannot be a parameter.  You need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: You will also have a problem with the datatype of @valuename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
1. DECLARE @value AS SMALLINT
2. DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
3. DECLARE @NameTable AS NVARCHAR(500)
4. DECLARE @field AS NVARCHAR(500)
5. SET @value = 2
6. SET @NameTable = 'Suppliers'
7. SET @field = 'Id'
8. SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM '+@NameTable+' WHERE '+@field+' = ' + 
   CAST(@value AS NVARCHAR(10))
9. EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL

Example:

```
DECLARE @nametable VARCHAR(150)='MyTable' --You can change the name here
DECLARE @fieldname VARCHAR(150)='MyField'
DECLARE @valuename INT=4                  --You must be careful here because you have to know the datatype of field to determine data type of parameter

DECLARE @sqlToExecute  AS NVARCHAR(MAX) =N'select * from ['+ @nametable +'] where ['+ @fieldname +'] = ' + @valuename

EXEC (@sqlToExecute)
```

Comment: This will work most of the time, but is a gaping SQL Injection hole. You *need* to be validating your input strongly before getting this far, or your app is wide open to the world.

Answer (score 0):

i think in addition to dynamic SQL,
using the database information schema is useful in search scenarios which you can in a way or another to employ for filtering or validating the tables and fields names you want to search in.
For example:
suppose your database name is "dbname" that contains some inventory tables that share the prefix "invent" in their names, and you want to search in these inventory tables only ... so you can loop through the result set of the following simple query:

```
    select Table_Name      ,Column_Name      ,Data_Type      ,Character_Maximum_Length, *
from dbname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME like 'invent%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Create dynamic search  SQL server stored procedure

```
Create PROCEDURE CUSTOMER.GET_DynamicSearch
(
    -- Optional Filters for Dynamic Search
    @CustomerID            INT = NULL,
    @CustomerName          NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @CustomerTitle         NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @locationId            int = NULL,
    @ControlCardNumber     bigint = NULL,
    @Formnumber            int = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE
    @lCustomerID            INT = NULL,
    @lCustomerName          NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @lCustomerTitle         NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @llocationId            int = NULL,
    @lControlCardNumber     bigint = NULL,
    @lFormnumber            int = NULL

    SET @lCustomerID          = @CustomerID
    SET @lCustomerName         = LTRIM(RTRIM(@CustomerName))
    SET @lCustomerTitle          = LTRIM(RTRIM(@CustomerTitle))
    SET @llocationId           = LTRIM(RTRIM(@locationId))
    SET @lControlCardNumber    = @ControlCardNumber
    SET @lFormnumber             = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Formnumber))

    SELECT
        c.CustomerId,
        c.CustomerName,
        c.CustomerTitle,
        c.LocationId,
        c.ControlCardNumber,
        c.FormNumber
    FROM CUSTOMER.Customer c
    WHERE
        (@lCustomerID IS NULL OR CustomerId = @lCustomerID)
    AND (@lCustomerName IS NULL OR CustomerName LIKE  '%' +@lCustomerName + '%')
    AND (@lCustomerTitle IS NULL OR CustomerTitle LIKE '%' + @lCustomerTitle + '%')
    AND (@llocationId IS NULL OR locationId = @llocationId )
    AND (@lControlCardNumber IS NULL OR ControlCardNumber = @lControlCardNumber)
    AND (@lFormnumber IS NULL OR Formnumber = @lFormnumber)
    ORDER BY c.CustomerID asc

END
GO
```

Execution Details

```
EXEC CUSTOMER.GET_DynamicSearch -- 2000  records
```

-- On providing only CustomerName parameter:

```
EXEC CUSTOMER.GET_DynamicSearch @CustomerName= 'Uttam' -- 1040 records
```